# Visual Studio and C# and Web Developer Productivity Tools /Helps

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking into Productivity tools for developing in C# / Visual Studio 2008 (pr0) and developing web apps (not using MVC).

Anything from favourite visual studio shortcuts to external tools and plug-ins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very interesting one that was just announced is [Telerik's JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx).  It's basically a new refactoring tool (such as [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/), also very good productivity improvement tools), but also handles Javascript in web projects.

Tools like these can dramatically improve the amount you can get done in a short amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

`Ctrl+.` is one of my favorites. It adds a Using statement for the current class if you don't already have it.

For example if you have this:

```
Regex
```

And you hit `Ctrl+.`. Visual Studio will add

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

to the top of your file.

I also like Code [Rush and Refactor Pro](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/) from DevExpress.

Answer (score 2):

ANTS Profiler from Red Gate helped our company find a lot of bottlenecks in our C# code.

Answer (score 2):

Reflector from Red Gate 
 PowerCommands visual studio add-in 
 any form of Grep

Answer (score 0):

We've just started using [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) which is pretty useful for quickly generating outlines of comments especially when you're generating your documentation from your XML comments. It's definitely saved me some time.

Answer (score 0):

its not a tool but a big reference chart - you can print it out and hang it on at your work area, to refer quick key bindings http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7162